# Is it possible to use AC (such as 1x150 mm²...) cable in DC application?

Tags: power, cables

Someone told me that 0.6/1 kVAC cable (1 × 150 mm<sup>2</sup>) can be use for rated DC voltage up to 1500 VDC and I wonder if he right?  He did not gave any explanation.

If yes, what are the calculation or conversion rules which based on standards?

Comment: What does '0.6' in "0.6/1 kVAC cable" refer to?

Comment: - unearthed AC Systems having continuous operating voltage between conductors of maximum 1.0 kV;
- single-phase, earthed AC Systems, having an operating voltage between conductors of maximum 0.6 kV

Comment: https://powerwhips.com/understanding-cable-voltage-ratings/

Comment: Thanks but there is no explanation to my question there...

Comment: If the RMS voltage is 1kV, then the peak voltage is close to 1.5kV thus the implication of 1.5kV DC. I’d suggest you check with the cable manufacturer before making any assumptions.

Comment: @winny. That was the point I was trying to communicate.

Comment: @Kartman Ah, then I misunderstood you.

Answer (score 1):

The two ratings are phase-ground and phase-phase.  Given that this is a single core cable, the former would be relevant if you placed a single wire on a grounded plate, whilst the latter if you placed two wires next to each other, typically with different phases in a 3 phase system.  Note that in the second case there is double the amount of insulation between the actual conductors, hence the higher rating.

The peak voltage for AC is 1.41xVrms, so a 0.6kV is likely good for about 850V DC, 1kV about 1400V.  If your 1500V DC application was balanced relative to ground (+/- 750V), you might well be okay using two of these wires next to each other.  If one side was grounded, and the other at 1500V relative to ground, then that wire's insulation would be significantly outside spec.

Either way, if you are considering a 150mm² cable at 1500V you have a high power application, with the potential for dangerous failure modes.  **You should absolutely *not* use the cable without getting explicit confirmation of DC suitability for your application from datasheet information, or better from the manufacturer.**